# Use "Shift + arrow key" to select multiple suggestions in magic suggest

Tags: jquery, magicsuggest

I wanted to customize to use "Shift + arrow key" to select multiple suggestions on the magicsuggest plug-in..

`JSFiddle` - http://jsfiddle.net/ZyA7B/16/

Step 1 : User selecting the suggestions using SHIFT (or) CTRL key :

Step 2 : Once selected the multiple suggestions and get the value in the textbox as follows below:

Step 1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhauA.png

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your efforts, and what specific problem you are faced with?

Comment: Updated the post and attached the snapshot of my screen...

Comment: First: en event keydown read if shift is pressed and is down or up arrow pressed also.
Secondary: on EVERY keydown event save to global value PREVIOUSLY highlighted option. 
Finally: i hope that magicsuggest have something like setting options throug json object: "{ VALUE(or values): [option1, option2]}"

Comment: @RamkumarMani: SO likes to preserve answers and questions for posterity's sake. Linking to external content, while helpful if used as additional information, is not a guaranteed way that a future reader can access that information. Sorry if I seem like a whiner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the customized plug-in which supports SHIFT + CTRL key to select multiple selection on the autocomplete.

```
Demo Here : [http://jsfiddle.net/jcxbgomd/][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer: i'm the plugin author)

That's not currently possible, as of this recent 2.0.0 release.
You can always fork the project. You would have to rewrite part of the handlers _onKeyUp and _onKeyDown which currently mitigates the usage of Shift, Ctrl, etc.... during selection.